# Create HTML Element with text that extends into border

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an HTML element that looks like this:-

[image]

Basically, a `<div>` or other element with a border, and the internal (possibly multi-line) text centred within the div, but extending into the border area.

So far, the only scheme I have that works is to use three(!) divs : One for the border, a second one as a container for the third one, to ensure the vertical centring is right.

```
<div class="BORDER" style = "left: 190px; top: 50px;">
</div>

<div class = "WRAPPER" style = "left: 190px; top: 50px;">
  <div>TEST THREE</div>
</div>
```

This feels awkward: Is there a way of achieving the same look using fewer elements?

Restrictions (clarified)

- The text can have one or more lines
- The border will be an image, and will eventually be stretched via the `border-image` mechanism.

JSFiddle with CSS and some other (failed) attempts is here. http://jsfiddle.net/6wB3k/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's adaptable to your real use case but I can achieve your display with only one div :

**HTML :**

```
<div class=dystroy>TEST FOUR</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.dystroy {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50px; top: 50px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 16px;
  height : 48px;
  width : 50px;
  display : table-cell;
  vertical-align : middle;
  text-align : center;
  color:  #000000;
  font-size : 16px;
  font-family : Calibri;
}

.dystroy:after {
  position: relative; 
  display : table-cell;
  top: -48px; left:0px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 16px 16px;
  border-color: #e0e0e0;
  height: 32px;
  width: 50px;
  content:" ";
  z-index:-1;
  font-size : 16px;
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/xu3mb/)

EDIT : in fact there's no real dynamic vertical centering here, which would need an additional div.

Comment: Well, I've learnt something ;-) But, the vertical centering isn't right. and the border in an odd way according to the number of text lines.

Comment: Yes, but as you hardcode the heights in your example, it's not clear what kind of vertical centering you want. You saw you can adjust the value ?

Comment: The 'box' height (and position) are hardcoded, but there might be one,two or three lines of text within the box. The text needs to be centred vertically within the box.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the best way to go. Some minor tweaks and I've added the second DIV here: http://jsfiddle.net/H8u8h/ Does that look OK top you?

Comment: @Roddy This is pretty :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are open to use CSS3 shadows, then you can try this:

Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/6wB3k/2/**

```
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 11px #ccc inset;
}
```

Syntax: `box-shadow: x-offset y-offset blur spread #color inset`

You can experiment with `blur` and `size` to adjust according to your requirements.

**Update**:

As per your comment regarding the need to use border-image, here is one try using `background-image` instead of a 9-grid `border-image`. I think, this can suit your purpose of using images?

Updated Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/6wB3k/3/**

```
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;

    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/11x11), url(http://placehold.it/11x11), url(http://placehold.it/11x11), url(http://placehold.it/11x11);
    background-position: left top, left bottom, top right, bottom right;
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-y, repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: +1 Not a complete answer (lacks the correct positioning) but an interesting one.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. Unfortunately I need a css border-image rather than a plain border. I'd removed that from the fiddle to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Please [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181774/stricter-kbd-usage-rules)

Comment: @dystroy: thanks. sorry for the misuse of kbd. updated.

Comment: @Roddy: as per your requirement of images, i have updated the answer. however, not with border-image but with background-image.

Answer (score 2):

The following works:

```
<div style="border: 9px solid #ccc; width: 40px;">
    <p style="margin: 0 -.5em;">Test text</p>
</div>
```

However, if you're spilling over your border, it's not strictly a border in the literal sense so much as it is a background image; perhaps there's another way of looking at your layout?

Comment: @Roddy I agree about the question not wanting a border technically. Achieving this with a background-image seems to make more sense. Heights and widths are much more flexible if you don't hack in a pseudo border.

Comment: You're right, except that my `background-image` *must* scale using the 9-grid technique that `border-image` supports. I can't see any easy way round that.